# Server side session management in NextJs

Tags: session, next.js, app-router

I want to use app router & server components in nextjs.  Server component calls api to some private domain. These api needs some access token which is generated in server component before hitting api. I do not want to generate this token in every server component before hitting api, instead I want to store this token in session which can be used at every api hit from server components.

Earlier I was using page router & iron-session, so when first time api was hit from some react component I use iron-session to save it in session. But iron-session internally set some cookie & setting cookie is not possible in server components.

So how can I use server session in nextjs for storing any information?